# Is it possible to run a method after a then() which returns an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object, promise

I'm trying to run an action right after the `.then()` method runs & return an `object`. For simplicity, let's say I have this code snippet:

```js
const functionToRunAfterWards = () => { // does stuff };

module.exports = {
  someFunction: ({ someParam }) => {
    
      return anotherFunction.then((someValue) => {
         // do a bunch of stuff
         return someStuff
      })
  },
};
```

The code snippet above works, but I want to run a `function` after `then()` returns `someStuff`. I tried running the `functionToRunAfterWards` function outside of `someFunction`, but it says `code cannot be accessed`. I also tried adding another `.then()`, but it won't work...like so:

```js
const functionToRunAfterWards = () => { // does stuff };

module.exports = {
  someFunction: ({ someParam }) => {
    
      return anotherFunction.then((someValue) => {
         // do a bunch of stuff
         return someStuff
      }).then(functionToRunAfterWards());
  },
};
```

Any idea on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Don't call your function when you pass it to `.then()`: `.then(functionToRunAfterWards);`

Comment: ... and maybe give it an argument, otherwise the content of `someStuff` will not be visible.

Comment: Adding to what @NickParsons says: By invoking your function in `then(functionToRunAfterwards())` you're passing _the return value of your function_ to `then` instead of the function itself.

Comment: you can do something like `then(()=>{functionToRunAfterWards()})`

Comment: @cars10m you nailed with this comment, is there way I could get the value of `someStuff` as well? Tried passing arguments to function `functionToRunAfterWards` but no luck

Comment: `.then(fn1)` will return a new promise which can again be handled by a chained `.then(fn2)`, like: `myPromise.then(fn1).then(fn2)`. It is important that you provide a function fn1 that expects an argument (the data, i. e.: `someStuff`) in it and, of course, you need to `return` the data in that function if you want to process it with fn2 in a following `.then(fn2)` (fn2 must also expect an argument!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promises' `then` accept a function. So, it should be:

```
blahBlahPromise.then(functionToRunAfterWards)
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine, but I'm not able to receive the value of `someStuff`, how do I get it as well?

Comment: Can you share more code? FYI, `someStuff` is always part of the promise chain. So you need to keep chaining `blahBlahPromise.then(functionToRunAfterWards).then((someStuff) => { //someStuff passed down from the previous .then call })`. You can't access it synchronously because JS is async (basically main thread will have executed and now it's waiting for event callbacks only)